# Keep common lines in a layout handle

Tags: magento-1.8

In my project, I have many layout handles which I am calling on different MVC actions (mostly on click). I just realized that the layout handles have a common code between them something like this:

```
<block name="reports.product.viewed" type="a/b_c" template="a/c.phtml"></block>
<block name="catalog.product.new" type="b/b_c" template="b/c.phtml"></block>
<block name="customer.allreviews" type="c/b_c" template="c/c.phtml"></block>
<block name="best.sellers" type="d/b_c" template="d/c.phtml"></block>
```

So, I planned to move the above code in a layout handle `common_code_lines` and call the layout handle instead of writing the above four lines. i.e

```
<reference name="content">
    <!-- other blocks -->
    <update handle="common_code_lines"/>
</reference>
```

This is just not working.. no errors.

What I am missing? please help.

Answer (score 1):

You still need to reference the parent block inside the handle, this means, layout handles are not replaced by the code. Instead they are processed too.

Instead of doing this, which is not possible...

```
<block name="reports.product.viewed" type="a/b_c" template="a/c.phtml"></block>
<block name="catalog.product.new" type="b/b_c" template="b/c.phtml"></block>
<block name="customer.allreviews" type="c/b_c" template="c/c.phtml"></block>
<block name="best.sellers" type="d/b_c" template="d/c.phtml"></block>

<reference name="content">
    <!-- other blocks -->
    <update handle="common_code_lines"/>
</reference>
```

You can do this:

```
<reference name="content">
    <block name="reports.product.viewed" type="a/b_c" template="a/c.phtml"></block>
    <block name="catalog.product.new" type="b/b_c" template="b/c.phtml"></block>
    <block name="customer.allreviews" type="c/b_c" template="c/c.phtml"></block>
    <block name="best.sellers" type="d/b_c" template="d/c.phtml"></block>
</reference>
```

And inside the other handle's root:

```
<update handle="common_code_lines"/>
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you..

Answer (score 1):

Assume you want to call `common_code_lines` handler inside the `sample_text_test`handler.

Then your code should be like this. Put `<update ... />` node just after the handler `sample_text_test`.

E.g.

```
<sample_text_test>
    <update handle="common_code_lines"/>
    <reference name="content">
        <!-- other blocks ..>
    </reference>
</sample_text_test>
```

> Note: The  node means, Take the layout update handle
>    and merge it’s contents with the current layout
>   xml.